# can't display extended file attributes on mac

Tags: macos, filesystems, ls

If I have the following output for a ls -l command on mac :

```
 total 0 
 -rw-rw-r--@ 1 <redicated>  <redicated> 0 Mar 23 15:54 filename
```

In the man page I read that `ls -@` displays the extended attribute keys. 
But for `ls -@` just the filename is printed to the terminal. 
For `ls -@ filname` I get `ls: filename: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list the files an entry per line. Like:

```
ls -l@
```